# The code doesn't work Even when I try to use a function in the left_action_items

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

**The code throws an error whenever I run it**

*Here's the code*

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder





KV = '''
Screen:
    NavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:"vertical"
                    MDToolbar:
                        title:"Tool"
                        left_action_items : [["menu", lambda x : app.menu]]
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "App"
'''


class GoodApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        builder = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return builder
    def menu(self):
        print("menu")**strong text**
GoodApp().run()
```

*Here's Here's the error :*

return self.proxy is not None and not bool(dir(self.proxy))
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists

Comment: I don't get the error with the weak-ref. For me, only the `NavigationLayout` and the `print("menu")` line are not working. After changing `NavigationLayout` to `MDNavigationLayout` and `print("menu")` (with-out the "strong text") the app starts with-out an error message.

Comment: I created a small demo to show how to get a button into the navigation drawer and trigger a log message `on_press`. Please find the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/AWolf81/7648acc47b897979a0f47785ea70fc5e). It's the code from the [docs](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/navigationdrawer/) with some changes.